# Some problems with libgtk-x11-2.0 lib and libgtk-3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gtk, shared-libraries, x11

When I execute my app (rails s) into my vagrant VM I found this problem:

```shell
vagrant@myapp:/vagrant$ rails s
Could not open library 'libgtk-x11-2.0': libgtk-x11-2.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
Could not open library 'libgtk-x11-2.0.so': libgtk-x11-2.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
Could not open library 'libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0': libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
Could not open library 'libgtk-3': libgtk-3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
Could not open library 'libgtk-3.so': libgtk-3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
Could not open library 'libgtk-3.so.0': libgtk-3.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.13 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2014-02-02 15:20:44] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2014-02-02 15:20:44] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2013-02-22) [i686-linux]
[2014-02-02 15:20:44] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2035 port=3000
```

I'm looking into my **Synaptic Package Manager**, but **I can't found** the lib **libgtk-x11-2.0**.

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 (precise32.box for Vagrant).
Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, it was resolved.I'm found the solucion in [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157941/how-to-make-machinarium-work-again)

```shell
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386 (from AskUbuntu).
```

Because it's a 32-bit binary and requires the 32-bit version of libgtk, but I had to install others dependecies.

```shell
sudo apt-get install libgtkmm-3.0-1
sudo apt-get install libnotify4
```

And problem resolved.

Comment: I just wanted to throw it out there that I had the same issue, and was able to resolve it by installing libgtkmm* and libnotify4.

Answer (score 0):

solved with:

```
sudo apt install -y libgtkmm-3.0-1v5 libnotify4
```