# Error when loading imutils: libgtk-3.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, imutils

I was trying to code a motion detection mechanism on my raspberry pi with Python when I ran into this problem. When I installed both imutils and opencv-python and attempted to run my program, this error message shows up.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "catfeeder.py", line 1, in <module>
    import imutils
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/imutils/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .convenience import translate
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/imutils/convenience.py", line 6, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: libgtk-3.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The same error appears if I attempt to import cv2.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "catfeeder.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: libgtk-3.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I fixed this after some attempts and searching. I installed the dependencies from the accepted answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556612/some-problems-with-libgtk-x11-2-0-lib-and-libgtk-3) and it got fixed, in case anyone else run into the same problem that I did.